# Determine list of all possible products from a list of integers in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

In Python 2.7 I need a method that returns all possible products of a `list or tuple of int`. Ie. if input is `(2, 2, 3, 4)`, then I'd want a output like

- `(3, 4, 4)`, 2 * 2 = 4
- `(2, 4, 6)`, 2 * 3 = 6
- `(2, 3, 8)`, 2 * 4 = 8
- `(3, 4, 4)`, 2 * 2 = 4
- `(2, 2, 12)`, 3 * 4 = 12
- `(2, 24)`, 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
- `(3, 16)`, 2 * 2 * 4 = 16
- `(4, 12)`, 2 * 2 * 3 = 12
- `(48)`, 2 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 48

wrapped up in a `list or tuple`. I figure that a nice implementation is probably possible using [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from `itertools`, but I'd appreciate any help. Note that I am only interested in distinct lists, where order of `int` plays no role.

EDIT

Some futher explanation for some clarification. Take the first output list. Input is `(2, 2, 3, 4)` (always). Then I take 2 and 2 *out* of the list and multiply them, so now I am left with a list `(3, 4, 4)`. 3 and 4 from the input and the last 4 from the product.

I haven't tried anything yet since I just can't spin my head around that kind of loop. But I can't stop thinking about the problem, so I'll add some code if I do get a suggestion.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I haven't tried anything yet since I just can't spin my head around that kind of loop. I noticed that I got a lot of minus for this question. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your output is not clear. For example, why is the tuple `(3, 4, 4)` before the product `2 * 2 = 4`? Also, you probably got downvotes because you did not show any code of your own, you gave desired output that makes no sense, and in general you showed very little work of your own. You could edit your question to solve these issues, and you would probably soon get upvotes and some good answers. I encourage you to do such editing.

Comment: @mr.bjerre Yes. If you simply cannot find a way to do this, make sure your output is clearly defined, and you show clear and easy to understand examples for your problem.

Comment: @RoryDaulton input is `(2, 2, 3, 4)`. Then I take 2 and 2 _out_ of the list and multiply them, so now I am left with a list `(3, 4, 4)`. 3 and 4 from the input and the last 4 from the product. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks for your clarification. I see you have just added that explanation to your question--well done! Now add the explanation "I haven't tried anything yet since I just can't spin my head around that kind of loop", or show some code of your own. It would also help to clarify what you mean by putting that output into a list or tuple. Do you mean a list/tuple of strings showing each line of what you showed, just the way you showed it?

Comment: @RoryDaulton and Mr.goosberry thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I think you can break this problem down into (1) get all the unique permutations of those lists, (2) get all the partitions of those permutations, (3) multiply the numbers in each partition.

Comment: @tobias_k you might be right, but what is meant by a partition of a permutation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can break this down into three steps:

- get all the permutations of the list of numbers
- for each of those permutations, create all the possible partitions
- for each sublist in the partitions, calculate the product

For the permutations, you can use `itertools.permutations`, but as far as I know, there is no builtin function for partitions, but that's not too difficult to write (or to find):

```
def partitions(lst):
    if lst:
        for i in range(1, len(lst) + 1):
            for p in partitions(lst[i:]):
                yield [lst[:i]] + p
    else:
        yield []
```

For a list like `(1,2,3,4)`, this will generate `[(1),(2),(3),(4)]`, `[(1),(2),(3,4)]`, `[(1),(2,3),(4)]`, `[(1),(2,3,4)]`, and so on, but not, e.g. `[(1,3),(2),(4)]`; that's why we also need the permutations. However, for all the permutations, this will create many partitions that are effectively duplicates, like `[(1,2),(3,4)]` and `[(4,3),(1,2)]` (182 for your `data`), but unless your lists are particularly long, this should not be too much of a problem.

We can combine the second and third step; this way we can weed out all the duplicates as soon as they arise:

```
data = (2, 2, 3, 4)
res = {tuple(sorted(reduce(operator.mul, lst) for lst in partition))
       for permutation in itertools.permutations(data)
       for partition in partitions(permutation)}
```

Afterwards, `res` is `{(6, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 2, 3, 4), (2, 2, 12), (48,), (3, 4, 4), (4, 12), (3, 16), (2, 24), (2, 3, 8)}`

---

Alternatively, you can combine it all in one, slightly more complex algorithm. This still generates *some* duplicates, due to the two `2` in your data set, that can again be removed by sorting and collecting in a set. The result is the same as above.

```
def all_partitions(lst):
    if lst:
        x = lst[0]
        for partition in all_partitions(lst[1:]):
            # x can either be a partition itself...
            yield [x] + partition
            # ... or part of any of the other partitions
            for i, _ in enumerate(partition):
                partition[i] *= x
                yield partition
                partition[i] //= x
    else:
        yield []

res = set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in all_partitions(list(data)))
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to permute a set, all "permutations" of a set have the same partitions. Also partition is not the right approach to this problem, by taking partitions you're over-solving this problem, then you're sweeping it under the rug by sorting things and feeding everything into a set.

Comment: @BiRico I am not creating permutationsof a set but of a list (actually, a tuple), and the permutations are necessary, because `(2,2,3,4)` has different partitions than `(2,3,2,4)`.

Comment: @BiRico Read the code I posted. ;-) Yes, the link points to partitions of a set, but the algo is creating partitions of a list (which are different and depend on order), not least because it is much simpler. Also, a true partitions-of-set algorithm would not work, since the input is not a set (there are two number 2 in it)

Comment: I don't know why your'e fighting me on this :) I'm trying to teach you something. You code generates 192 results for a problem that should have 11 results ... something is amiss.

Comment: @BiRico I am perfectly aware of this and pointed out that there are duplicates, that are to be filtered out by sorting and by collecting them in a set. But unless OP tells us that his lists are particularly long, I do not consider this a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123067/discussion-between-bi-rico-and-tobias-k).

Comment: @BiRico Removed misleading link, expained how partitions look and why permutations, and added an alternative solution with fewer duplicates (only those related to having duplicate numbers in the input). Better?

Comment: Thank you. It solves my problem. When I find the time for it, I might try to improve it by not 'oversolving', but for now it is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basically one of find all subsets of a given set (multiset in your case). Once you have the subsets its straight forward to construct the output you've asked for.

For a set A find all the subsets [S0, S1, ..., Si]. For each subset Si, take `(A - Si) | product(Si)`, where `|` is union and `-` is a set difference. You might not be interested in subsets of size 0 and 1, so you can just exclude those.

Finding subsets is a well known problem so I'm sure you can find resources on how to do that. Keep in mind that there are 2**N setbsets of a set with N elements.

Comment: Very precise. I'll try to come up with my own algorithm based on this. Although for now; tobias_k's code will be sufficient.  I'd up your answer if I'd have the necessary points for it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a vector of 4 numbers (for instance (2,2,3,4)).

You can generate a grid (as that one showed below):

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

Now remove the rows with all '0' and the rows with only one '1'.

```
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

Now you can substitute the '1' with the respective element in the vector.
If your vector is (2,2,3,4) it becomes:

```
0 0 3 4
0 2 0 4
0 2 3 0
0 2 3 4
2 0 0 4
2 0 3 0
2 0 3 4
2 2 0 0
2 2 0 4
2 2 3 0
2 2 3 4
```

Try to implement this in Python.
Below a pseudo code:

```
for i from 0 to 2^VECTOR_LEN:
    bin=convert_to_binary(i)
    if sum_binary_digit(bin) > 1:
       print(exec_moltiplication(bin,vector) 
       # if you want you can also use the bin vector as mask for the updating 
       # of your tuple of int with the result of the product and append it
       # in a list (as in your example).
       # For example if bin is (1 1 0 0) you can edit (2 2 3 4) in (4 3 4)
       # and append (4 3 4) inside the list or if it is (1 0 1 0) you can 
       # update (2 2 3 4) in (6 2 4)
```

WHERE:

- vector: is the vector containing the numbers
- VECTOR_LEN is the length of vector
- convert_to_binary(num) is a function that convert an integer (num) to binary
- sum_binary_digit(bin) is a function that sum the 1s in your binary number (bin)
- exec_multiplication(vector,bin) take in input the vector (vector) and the binary (bin) and returns the value of the multiplication.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense whatsoever. How does this address the OP's problem?

Comment: Thanks for the effort - it does cast some light on the problem for me. I'd up your answer if I'd have the necessary points for it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the algo(as i don't know it myself), but there is lib which can achieve this task...
Looking at you given input numbers, they seem to be factors, so if we multiply all of these factors we get a number(say x), now using sympy, we can get all of the divisors of that number:--

```
import numpy
ls = [2,2,3,4]

x = numpy.prod(ls)

from sympy import divisors
divisors_x = divisors(x)
```

Here you go!! this the list(divisors_x )