# Python Combinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinations, python-itertools

Suppose I have a Python list that looks like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would like to be able to return a list of lists containing all combinations of two or more numbers. The order of the values doesn't matter so 1,2 is the same as 2,1.  I would also like to return another list that contains the values that do not feature in each combination. For example:

```
Combination 1,2 / Remainder 3,4
Combination 2,3 / Remainder 1,4
Combination 1,2,3 / Remainder 4
Combination 1,2,3,4/ Remainder -
```

The returned lists for the above would be

```
combination = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]
remainder = [[3,4], [1,4], [4], []]
```

I've only shown a few examples...

I realise that the first part can probably be achieved using `itertools.combinations` but how can I return those values not used in the combination without looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building upon the idea by [Nunzio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545624/1639625), but instead of converting numbers in a certain range to binary, you can just use `itertools.product` to get all combinations of `1` and `0` (or `True` and `False`) and then use that as a mask for filtering the "ins" and "outs".

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> products = list(product([1,0], repeat=len(lst)))
>>> [[lst[i] for i, e in enumerate(p) if e] for p in products]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [2], [3], []]
>>> [[lst[i] for i, e in enumerate(p) if not e] for p in products]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

You could also define a function for that `enumerate` comprehension and do both parts in one go:

```
>>> mask = lambda lst, p, v: [lst[i] for i, e in enumerate(p) if e == v]
>>> [(mask(lst, p, 1), mask(lst, p, 0)) for p in product([1,0], repeat=len(lst))]
[([1, 2, 3], []),
 ([1, 2], [3]),
 ([1, 3], [2]),
 ([1], [2, 3]),
 ([2, 3], [1]),
 ([2], [1, 3]),
 ([3], [1, 2]),
 ([], [1, 2, 3])]
```

If you only want combinations with 2 or more in the "in" list, you can add a condition:

```
>>> [(mask(lst, p, 1), mask(lst, p, 0)) for p in product([1,0],repeat=len(lst)) if sum(p) >= 2]
```

Or use `numpy` arrays and make use of `numpy`'s advanced indexing:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> [(arr[p==1], arr[p==0]) for p in map(np.array, product([1,0], repeat=len(arr)))]
[(array([1, 2, 3]), array([])),
 (array([1, 2]), array([3])),
 (array([1, 3]), array([2])),
 (array([1]), array([2, 3])),
 (array([2, 3]), array([1])),
 (array([2]), array([1, 3])),
 (array([3]), array([1, 2])),
 (array([]), array([1, 2, 3]))]
```

Comment: I love this solution! Works like a dream! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can take the set difference:

```
l = set([1, 2, 3, 4])

for i in range(len(l)+1):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(l, i):
        print(comb, l.difference(comb))

() {1, 2, 3, 4}
(1,) {2, 3, 4}
(2,) {1, 3, 4}
(3,) {1, 2, 4}
(4,) {1, 2, 3}
(1, 2) {3, 4}
(1, 3) {2, 4}
(1, 4) {2, 3}
(2, 3) {1, 4}
(2, 4) {1, 3}
(3, 4) {1, 2}
(1, 2, 3) {4}
(1, 2, 4) {3}
(1, 3, 4) {2}
(2, 3, 4) {1}
(1, 2, 3, 4) set()
```

Comment: Note that set difference will only work if the list contains no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this vector [1 6 3]

You can generate all of the numbers from 0 to 2^3-1 where 3 is `len([1 6 3])`

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

After you can convert this numbers to binary:

```
 0 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0
 0 1 1
 1 0 0
 1 0 1
 1 1 0
 1 1 1
```

Put your vector at the top of the sequence generated:

```
[1 6 3]
 0 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0
 0 1 1
 1 0 0
 1 0 1
 1 1 0
 1 1 1
```

for each line append in combination the number that are in the same position of the 1s and in the remainder that one that are in the position of the 0s.

so, for instance, looking at the 4th line:

```
Combination: [6,3]
Remainder: [1]
```

At the end:

```
Combination: [],[3],[6],[6,3],[1],[1,3],[1,6],[1,6,3]
Remainder: [1,6,3],[1,3],[1],[6,3],[6],[3],[]
```

Here the code:

```
vec=[1,3,6]
binary_vec = [format(i,'b').zfill(len(vec)) for i in range(2**len(vec))]
print([[vec[i] for i,y in enumerate(x) if y != "0"] for x in binary_vec])
print([[vec[i] for i,y in enumerate(x) if y == "0"] for x in binary_vec])
```

Output:

[image]

Look also at my answer in this post:

[Determine list of all possible products from a list of integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428179/determine-list-of-all-possible-products-from-a-list-of-integers-in-python/39428550#39428550)

Comment: Interesting approach. Could you also provide some code for that? Also, you could use `itertools.product([True, False],repeat=3)` instead of converting to binary.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you! I didn't know this function: itertools.product([True, False],repeat=3)! I also provided the code.